# IIF within a VBA With Structure

Tags: vba, excel

I have a With statement to access a structure I've developed for some code.  The structure has (where I'm working) two branches for Male and Female and I'm passing into the subroutine an Integer to specify the sex.

Roughly speaking I have

```
Type MyDetails
    green As Integer
    black As Integer
    yellow As Integer
    blue As Integer
End Type

Type Genders
    Males As MyDetails
    Females As MyDetails
End Type

Type GlobalData
   RegionName As String
   Ages(0..100) As Genders
End Type

Public Dim PopData As GlobalData
```

Then in my subroutine I have

```
With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)
    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        ... Do the stuff for males
    Else
        ... Do the exact same stuff but for females
    End If
End With
```

So my question is if I could get rid of the interior IF statement by putting an IIF statement into the WITH block ... or something equivalent.  This is mostly an academic question because the code works fine ... but it would be nicer not to have to duplicate all my code with the simple difference of changing all the **.Males.** to **.Females.** within each part of the If Cur_Sex = 0 Then block.

Thanks in advance.  Hope this makes sense.

I'm adding the actual code in question to hopefully make it clearer ...

Cur_Eth is short for Current Ethnicity
DistInfo is short for Population Ethnicity Distribution
Cur_Eth_Total is a Double which is the sum of .D + .M + .I + .N (for either Males or Females depending on when I call the routine).

```
With PopData(Cur_CSD).DistInfo
    Cur_Rand = Rnd
    Cur_Eth = -1
    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        Cur_Eth_Total = .Males.D + .Males.M + .Males.I + .Males.N
        Select Case Cur_Rand
            Case Is < CDbl(.Males.D) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 0
            Case Is < CDbl(.Males.D + .Males.M) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 1
            Case Is < CDbl(.Males.D + .Males.M + .Males.I) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 2
            Case Else
                Cur_Eth = 3
        End Select
    Else
        Cur_Eth_Total = .Females.D + .Females.M + .Females.I + .Females.N
        Select Case Cur_Rand
            Case Is < CDbl(.Females.D) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 0
            Case Is < CDbl(.Females.D + .Females.M) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 1
            Case Is < CDbl(.Females.D + .Females.M + .Females.I) / Cur_Eth_Total
                Cur_Eth = 2
            Case Else
                Cur_Eth = 3
        End Select
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a class, not a type.

Comment: Interesting thought.  You may be right, it may have been wiser to build it with a class originally.  At this point, I don't think I'll re-write all of my code to simply fix this one issue.  It's working ... I was just hoping to make it simpler to maintain.  But good thought for the future.

Comment: In general, the more functionality you can encapsulate into classes, the easier it will be to maintain. See [SOLID design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the suggestion by @cyboashu (so I'll mark his answer as the accepted solution even though his original answer wasn't what I'm using).

Instead of the Type statements I used, instead I'll use:

```
Type MyDetails
    green(1) As Integer ' For documentation purposes I could, perhaps should have used (0 To 1) to be explicit about the array dimensions.
    black(1) As Integer
    yellow(1) As Integer
    blue(1) As Integer
End Type

Type GlobalData
   RegionName As String
   Ages(0..100) As MyDetails
End Type
```

Then my resulting WITH statement could have been exactly as it is but the code would change only slightly to incorporate the sex (I'll rewrite my actual code here with the implementation of this concept)

```
With PopData(Cur_CSD).DistInfo
    Cur_Rand = Rnd
    Cur_Eth = -1
    Cur_Eth_Total = .D(Cur_Sex) + .M(Cur_Sex) + .I(Cur_Sex) + .N(Cur_Sex)
    Select Case Cur_Rand
        Case Is < CDbl(.D(Cur_Sex)) / Cur_Eth_Total
            Cur_Eth = 0
        Case Is < CDbl(.D(Cur_Sex) + .M(Cur_Sex)) / Cur_Eth_Total
            Cur_Eth = 1
        Case Is < CDbl(.D(Cur_Sex) + .M(Cur_Sex) + .I(Cur_Sex)) / Cur_Eth_Total
            Cur_Eth = 2
        Case Else
            Cur_Eth = 3
    End Select
End With
```

Cutting the amount of code in half but not making the code substantially less readable.

Comment: But I also really liked the answer from @GSerg

Comment: `Public Enum Sexes : Male : Female : End Enum` `Type MyDetails : green(Male To Female) As Integer : black(Male To Female) As Integer : yellow(Male To Female) As Integer : blue(Male To Female) As Integer :  End Type`

Comment: Good point @GSerg ... it's been a long time since I did any serious coding (I've been doing project management) ... and I knew Enumerated types would be useful ... just didn't take the time to review their syntax.  Thanks for the quick refresher!

Answer (score 5):

`IIf` is highly inefficient for calling methods through it. As long as you are doing simple variable assignments, its fine, but if you try to call Functions using your test condition you will run in trouble. The thing with `IIf` is that irrespective of True or False status of the condition it actually evaluates/executes both of the parameters.

So this may be sorter in terms of code, its highly inefficient in terms of execution.

See the example:

```
Function test1() As String
  MsgBox "Test1 called"
  test1 = "test1"
End Function

Function test2() As String
    MsgBox "Test2 called"
    test2 = "test2"
End Function

Sub Test()

    Dim x  As String
    Dim Y  As Long
    Dim Z  As String

    x = 0

    Y = IIf(x = 1, 1, 2)
    MsgBox Y

    '/ Although condition evaluates to false, it will still call test1 
    '/which is bound to true condition,before calling test2.
    Z = IIf(x = 1, test1, test2)
    MsgBox Z

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate that IIF may be inefficient ... but I'm not trying to call functions ... I'm doing math on the values within the Type structures I created and simply want to reduce the code that needs to be maintained if it can be done easily and without making it obscure for a future maintainer.  So this doesn't seem to really address my question at all.

Comment: @NWT_Bob I have maintained vba code that was 10+ years old. And i can tell you that unless your `IIF` is **extremely** simple (like in the exemple above) it is going to become a nightmare to maintain over time. And these 4 extra lines won't make it more maintainable at all.

Comment: I edited my original post a few minutes ago ... it's the final WITH structure that is currently written as: With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)
but could in theory (but I doubt it would work) be written as With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age).IIF(Cur_Sex=0,"Males","Females") so that it would actually directly reference just the section I'm working with (males or females) and then all of the code within the With block would be identical and the internal If Cur_Sex = 0 Then statement could be eliminated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all the details are same except sex then then get rid of `Genders` add one more property in MyDetails as `Sex` and use `MyDetails` array to store data. On the basis of sex you can always identify it later using `If` or `IIf`.

Comment: Ahhh ... yes, that would do it ... or a slight variation of that concept @cyboashu ... if I had created all my MyDetails elements as arrays with 2 elements green(0 to 1) As Integer ... then I could have simply used the Cur_Sex as the array index on MyDetails and eliminate the IF statement that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, in principle you want this:

```
With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)
    Dim ToProcess as Genders

    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        ToProcess = .Males
    Else
        ToProcess = .Females
    End If

    ' Use ToProcess
End With
```

You can do it with both classes and structures, but with different efficiency and an additional step you would need to make in case you want to write the data back to `PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)`.

If `Genders` was a class, you'd be able to write:

```
With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)
    Dim ToProcess as Genders

    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        Set ToProcess = .Male
    Else
        Set ToProcess = .Female
    End If

    ' Use ToProcess here. Both read and write actions will affect the original `PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)`.
End With
```

Because it's a structure, you need instead:

```
With PopData.Ages(Cur_Age)
    Dim ToProcess as Genders

    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        ToProcess = .Male
    Else
        ToProcess = .Female
    End If

    ' Use ToProcess here.
    ' If you only want to read from ToProcess, that's all you need.
    ' If you need to write changes back to PopData.Ages(Cur_Age), then you will also need:

    If Cur_Sex = 0 Then
        .Male = ToProcess
    Else
        .Female = ToProcess
    End If
End With
```